# Identify Digits in text field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

How is it possible to identify any values with ONLY text in text field

For instance;

```
Col1

THY1
D881
D282
RM01
D114
KAAR
5555
KAAR
KAAR
```

Expected Results

```
Results
With Digits
With Digits
With Digits
With Digits
With Digits
KAAR
With Digits
KAAR
KAAR
```

I tried below, doesn't work though

```
SELECT IIF(Tab1.Col1 LIKE "[!0-9]",  Tab1.Col1, "With Digits") AS Results
FROM  Tab1
```

Please clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1 from tab1 where col1 not like "%[0-9]%"
```

You should harness the power of "where" clause.

Update: Since you want to preserve order and replace improper values with "With Digits", the correct clause should be like this:

```
SELECT IIF(Tab1.Col1 LIKE "%[0-9]%",  "With Digits", Tab1.Col1) AS Results
FROM  Tab1;
```

Note the "%" signs, they make SQL to match 0-9 to any position of the `Tab1.Col1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case numbers can exist anywhere in the value. So needs to identified those values and list seperately

Comment: What do you mean under "value"? Is it just the contents of `col1`, or the entire row? If the former, then this clause filters out all values that contain `[0-9]` symbols anywhere. If the entire row, you can add similar constructs for other fields, separated by "and" statement. Say `where col1 not like "%[0-9]%" and col2 not like "%[0-9]%"`.

Comment: Or do you need to select all, but replace the improper values (that contain digits) by "With Digits"? If this, then using `IIF()` is the right approach. You have updated the question after my answer, though.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am after what you have mentioned at the end with `IIF() ` scenario. But problem is it doesn't give expected results. It gives all the results as `"With Digits" `. I updated only the Result set in my question.

Comment: Too weird, it should not. I have tested at w3schools, the similar query provides correct results over their tables. What if you copy&paste this query:  `SELECT IIF(Tab1.Col1 LIKE "%[0-9]%",  "With Digits", Tab1.Col1) AS Results, Tab1.Col1 as Originals FROM  Tab1;` and paste the results in here?

Comment: @ManthreePeiris Does this version give you what you want? `IIF(Tab1.Col1 ALIKE "%[0-9]%",  "With Digits", Tab1.Col1)`  Or this one? `IIF(Tab1.Col1 LIKE "*[0-9]*",  "With Digits", Tab1.Col1)`

Comment: Terrific HansUP both working fine. `ALIKE `  and `*[0-9]* ` made the difference. Much appreciate if you could explain reason behind

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backwards.  You are testing for the presence of any non-numeric.  Instead, look for the presence of any numeric:

```
SELECT IIF(Tab1.Col1 LIKE "[0-9]",  "With Digits", Tab1.Col1) AS Results
FROM  Tab1;
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. I have put `[!0-9] ` though, not `[0-9] `

Comment: @ManthreePeiris . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  The code in the question detects whether a single non-digit is in columns.  This determines if any of the numbers are digits.  This seems to answer your question.

Comment: Hello Gordon, The issue here is the expected results mentioned in the question wont give from these solutions. Not sure something wrong at my end.